# How tu use a custom validator with a service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I try to use a custom validator to check if email is already taken.
According to the documentation and some articles I came up with this code:

in my auth.service.ts

```
checkEmail(email) {
    const r$ = of(true);
    const x$ = of(false);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/email`, email)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(v =>
        iif(
          () => v,
          r$,
          x$
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

in my component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
        this.checkEmail.bind(this)
      ]]
    });
  }



checkEmail(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.value) {
      return this.authService.checkEmail({email: control.value}).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        return response ? { forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} : null;
        });
    }
  }
```

But it's not working, how can I make the checkEmail() function return the right data for the validator

Comment: First, this should be an async validator as far as I understand: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation Async validators are marked as [third argument](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor()), after sync validators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the following mods:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ], [this.checkEmail.bind(this)]] // async validators go separate after sync validators
    });
  }



  checkEmail(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.value) {
      return this.authService.checkEmail({email: control.value}).pipe(
        map(response => {
          return response ? { forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} : null;
         }) // use observables, don't convert to promises
       );
    }
    return of(null); // gotta return an observable for async
  }
```

not needed but this can also be simpler / cleaner:

```
  checkEmail(email) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/email`, email)
    .pipe(
      map(v => !!v) // map and coerce to bool
    );
  }
```